# How can i select required columns?

Tags: c#, sql

```
 var abc =
                from t1 in db.base3
                where db.base2.Any(t2 =>
                          db.base1.Any(t3 =>
                              t3.ed > startDate && t3.ed < endDate  && t3.request_id == t2.request_id
                        ) && t2.link_id == t1.PersonId
                )
                select t1;
```

Can't select columns from not only base3(t1), but base1(t3) at the same time

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a linq-statement like yours, the t2/t3 properties are not 'known' at the upmost level. You could see this a little bit like nestet loops in C#:

```
    foreach(var t1 in base3)
{
    // t1 is accessible here
    foreach(var t2 in base2)
    {
        // t1, t2 is accessible here
        foreach(var t3 in base1)
        {
            // t1, t2, t3 is accessible here
        }
    }
}
```

Besides this, there's no relation between base3-Properties and base1-Properties. If your Linq would use joins for the entities, you could access all properties, e.g.:

```
    var abc = (from t1 in db.base3
    join t2 in db.base2 on t1.PersonId equals t2.link_id
    join t3 in db.base1 on t2.request_id equals t3.request_id
    where t3.ed < DateTime.Now && t3.request_id < 20
    select new {t1.PersonId, t3.ed});
```